# last modified date does not match with the last modified date of the retrieved parameters

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm getting this error

```
 Failed to create ChangeSet cdk-deploy-change-set on production-ec2: FAILED, Parameters: [ssm:/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2:45:1619654085749] last modified date does not match with the last modified date of the retrieved parameters.
```

when trying to run `cdk deploy`

Some background:

1. I created the entire stack successfully with my local machine inside a docker image and my own user
2. I recreated this docker image on an ec2 with a role instead of my user credentials and then get this failure

I can't find anything on the web about this error, help appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error.

Comment: Looks like this is related to https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14629

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this in typescript

```js
const amznLinux = ec2.MachineImage.lookup({
  name: 'amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.*-x86_64-gp2',
  owners: ['amazon']
});
```

or in python

```py
machine_image = ec2.MachineImage.lookup(
    name='amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.*-x86_64-gp2',
    owners=['amazon']
)
```

This will do the CDK lookup at synth time and will not resolve the ssm parameter in the output CloudFormation template.

Comment: Oh, I pasted the wrong snippet before man, sorry for that. I have updated the answer now with the correct one.

Comment: @ChrisWatts please try again with the updated snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for the updated snippet. I'm still seeing the same error, unfortunately. In the cdk synth output I now see "ImageId": "ami-1234", for my BastionHost resource. I also see it trying to look up the AMI during synth time. The output is: "Searching for AMI in ****:us-east-1"

Comment: I just removed the bastion host and re-ran cdk deploy and things are working now.